# Ecto.NoResultsError render json

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the following controller in API which uses Phoenix.

```
defmodule TattooBackend.Web.API.V1.StudioController do
  use TattooBackend.Web, :controller

  alias TattooBackend.Accounts.Studio

  def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    studio = Repo.get!(Studio, id)

    render conn, studio: studio
  end
end
```

My goal here is to rescue globally Ecto.NoResultsError and render some error message. I can rewrite this into following format:

```
def show(conn,%{"id" => id}) do
  case Repo.get(Studio, id) do
    nil -> # return null and 404 
    record -> # do something with record        
  end
end
```

but I want to avoid repeating this pattern in other controllers. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You could customize the 404 error message in `MyApp.ErrorView` (`web/views/error_view.ex`). You'll only see that error in prod; in dev you'll see a more detailed error page.

Comment: But I also want to see json message that record has not been found in development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One could declare the custom error for `Ecto.NoResultsError` as [described here](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/custom-errors):

> ```
> defimpl Plug.Exception, for: Ecto.NoResultsError do
>   def status(_exception), do: 404
> end
> ```

As specified in the documentation, Phoenix provides a [default implementation](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_ecto/blob/master/lib/phoenix_ecto/plug.ex) for `Ecto.NoResultsError` and what you wanted should work out of the box.